# SQL Order by Second Letter of Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of lets say 10 values all NCHAR(20) in SQL Server.

I want to sort the Values by the 2nd Letter in a Descending manner. In other Words if i have the following column values. Note this should work with any values this is just examples.

- Earth
- Space
- Moon
- Star
- Pluto

The SQL Query must produce the Following Output

- Star
- Space
- Moon
- Pluto
- Earth

The closest I could come to an answer was This -

Select planet, name from galaxy
WHERE planet like '_%'
ORDER BY planet desc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(planet , 2, 1) DESC
```

It`s good to check the docs from time to time [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Comment: I did the Precise same one, instead i put a 2 instead of a 1 thinking the index starts at 0? Thanks alot it works

Comment: I used it in MySQL. Works anyway: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring  :) Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

You can `ORDER BY SUBSTR(planet, 2) DESC`

This means minus the first character.